# Customize the name of custom listings in their "list of"

Tags: table-of-contents, listings, naming

As I would like to separate the listings in my document, I decided to create two separate lists of them: one for the algorithms, and one for the sources.

In addition, the sources must be loaded from an external file.

So, with the following code in the preamble and inserting `\lstlistofsourcecode` in the right place I can achieve two separated lists.

```
\makeatletter
\let\oldaddcontentsline\addcontentsline
\newcommand{\lstlistsourcecodename}{Elenco dei codici}%
\lst@UserCommand\lstlistofsourcecode{\bgroup
    \let\contentsname\lstlistsourcecodename
    \let\lst@temp\@starttoc \def\@starttoc##1{\lst@temp{los}}
    \tableofcontents \egroup}%
\newcommand{\lstinputsourcecode}[2][]{{%
  \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Sorgente}
  \renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{\oldaddcontentsline{los}{##2}{##3}}%
  \lstinputlisting[#1]{#2}%
}}
\makeatother
```

The image shows the results:

[image]

The goal I want to achieve is to **change the name** of `\lstinputsourcecode` listings into their `los` (i.e., list of ...): from **"Algoritmo B.1"** to **"Sorgente B.1"**.

The strange behaviour is that `\lstlistingname` command works for the captions.

For example, if I do:

```
\lstinputsourcecode[language=cpp, caption=Esempio di funzione \acs{RTE} esportata, label=lst:callpoint-impl]{codes/callpointimpl.cpp}
```

Then I obtain the right caption (ie., **"Sorgente: ..."** in the image):

[image]

How can I tell to the `\lstlistofsourcecode` to use **"Sorgente"** and not **"Algoritmo"** ?

---

*Note*: I'm using the classicthesis template.

---

Thanks in advance.

### Solution

The final solution adopted (thanks to @Werner) is:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\sourcecodename}{Sorgente}
\let\oldaddcontentsline\addcontentsline
\newcommand{\listofsourcecodename}{Elenco dei sorgenti}%
\lst@UserCommand\listofsourcecode{\bgroup
  \let\contentsname\listofsourcecodename
  \let\lst@temp\@starttoc \def\@starttoc##1{\lst@temp{los}}
  \newlength{\sourcecodelabelwidth}
  \settowidth{\sourcecodelabelwidth}{\sourcecodename~999}
  \addtolength{\sourcecodelabelwidth}{1.8em}
  \def\l@lstlisting##1##2{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{\sourcecodelabelwidth}{##1}{##2}}
  \def\numberline##1{\hb@xt@\@tempdima{\sourcecodename{} ##1\hfil}}
  \tableofcontents \egroup}%
\newcommand{\inputsourcecode}[2][]{{%
  \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{\sourcecodename}%
  \renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{\oldaddcontentsline{los}{##2}{##3}}%
  \lstinputlisting[#1]{#2}%
}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Regardless of how complete this question may seem to you, it is always best and extremely appreciated if you could compose what is called a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) for the community to work with. Not only does it allow us to hit the ground running, it also speeds up getting solutions to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are possible elements you can include in your redefinition of `\lstlistofsourcecode`:

```
\lst@UserCommand\lstlistofsourcecode{\bgroup
    \let\contentsname\lstlistsourcecodename
    \let\lst@temp\@starttoc \def\@starttoc##1{\lst@temp{los}}
    \def\l@lstlisting##1##2{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{5.2em}{##1}{##2}}% Added
    \def\numberline##1{\hb@xt@\@tempdima{Sorgente ##1\hfil}}% Added
    \tableofcontents \egroup}%
```

The update to `\l@lstlisting` increases the space allocated for the `\numberline` macro from `2.3em` to `5.2em` (the third argument). You may want to experiment with this if you wish for it to be similar to the inclusion of your algorithms (I don't have a MWE replicating the situation, so I just guessed `5.2em`). The update to `\numberline` inserts `Sorgente` before the number as needed.

The reason for this type of "intervention" is because the setting of the listing and the listing ToC is completely separate. Packages like [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) ease this manual intervention.

Comment: I was trying to accomplish the same thing with `tocloft` and I had almost succeeded. I missed the inclusion of entry (precisely of its caption) ..